# Select all rows if only one matches

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables: `FEATURE` and `FEATURE_DETAILS`. Relation is one(`FEATURE`) to many(`FEATURE_DETAILS`).

```
feature_details_id | feature_id
1                        1
1                        2
1                        4 
2                        1
2                        2
2                        4
2                        5
3                        1
3                        5
```

How could I select all rows which contains e.g. 5?

```
feature_details_id | feature_id
2                        1
2                        2
2                        4
2                        5
3                        1
3                        5
```

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2012/12-mar/o22sql-1494267.html you should read some books on SQL

Answer (score 3):

first get the list of feature_deatails_id for which feature_id is 5, then pass the `feature_deatails_id` to `FEATURE_DETAILS` table to get the result

Try something like this

```
select * 
from FEATURE_DETAILS 
where feature_deatails_id in(
                  select feature_deatails_id from FEATURE_DETAILS where feature_id = 5)
```

or use `Max()Over()` Window function(preferred approach)

```
select * from 
(
select max(case when feature_id = 5 then 1 else 0 end)over(partition by feature_deatails_id) as cnt,
       feature_deatails_id,feature_id 
from FEATURE_DETAILS 
)s
Where cnt = 1
```

Comment: Why is `Max()Over()` preferred?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM FEATURE_DETAILS WHERE feature_details_id IN (
  SELECT feature_details_id from FEATURE_DETAILS WHERE feature_id=5
)
```